# I don't get align my input checkbox in form

Tags: css

I have the following form, but I don't get align checkbox

```
<!-- Multiple Checkboxes (inline) -->
<div class="form-row">
<label class="chkdonar" for="donarchkform-0">Si, quiero donar a AMIAB</label>
<input id="donarchkform-0" checked="checked" name="donarchkform" type="checkbox" value="Si, quiero donar a AMIAB" />
</label>
```

this is the field where I have problem for getting align

Here is my code from the form

http://jsbin.com/mazuyinobu/edit?html,css,output

I would like to align my form look like this:

http://www.amiab.com/hacerte-socio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope i didn't edit your own jsbin.

http://jsbin.com/pewariguro/1/edit?html,css,output

Here's what I've done:

1. No need for negative margin on div.
2. Set margin to 0 on the inputs
3. Make sure the text fits on 1 line.
4. Align the checkbox to the left.